# how to create url slug with certain words(root directory names) excluded?

Tags: php

I am allowing my website user's to specify their own slug for the page they create for better seo purpose.
 what I am trying to do is I want to restrict the user from specifying the directory names present in the root. e.g. I am having dir with name 'abc' then user should not be able to use this name as slug e.g. www.mywebsite.com/abc should be flagged as invalid because 'abc' is directory name present at my project root level. what could be the good approach for avoiding root directory names as slug?

Comment: just check on server `if (is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $slug)) {/*fail*/}`

Comment: the above piece does solve my purpose thanks @Serjio